# Vite dynamic imports

Tags: create-react-app, vite

I am trying to write dynamic imports in Vite. In a regular CRA they were implemented like this

```js
const Components = {};

Components[0] = require('./ContentBuilderTemplate0').default;
Components[1] = require('./ContentBuilderTemplate1').default;
```

similar code in Vite throws errors because the require directive is not allowed.

My solution was this

```js
const Components = {};
const componentIndices = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, '3-secondary', 4, ...];

const asyncImportComponents = async() => {
   for (const index of componentIndices) {
     const importPath = index === '3-secondary'
       ? `./ContentBuilderTemplate3Secondary.tsx`
       : `./ContentBuilderTemplate${index}.tsx`;
     const componentModule = await import(importPath);
     Components[index] = componentModule.default;
   }
};

asyncImportComponents();
```

but it also threw an error:
The above dynamic import cannot be analyzed by Vite.
See https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/dynamic-import-vars#limitations for supported dynamic import formats. If this is intended to be left as-i
s, you can use the /* @vite-ignore */ comment inside the import() call to suppress this warning.

My Vite settings

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react';
import viteTsconfigPaths from 'vite-tsconfig-paths';
import svgrPlugin from 'vite-plugin-svgr';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  server: {
    port: 3000,
    proxy: {
      '/media': {
        target: 'http://websites.dataart.com/',
        changeOrigin: true,
      },
    }
  },
  plugins: [react(), viteTsconfigPaths(), svgrPlugin()],
  envDir: './envs',
});
```